# Reinstall Python Package

Tags: python

I created a small Python package. As I'm making modifications, I've found that I need to do the following in order for the changes to take effect:

1. `cd` to the package's root directory (same as where `setup.py` is located)
2. `pip uninstall <package_name>`
3. delete the `build` directory that was created when the package was last installed
4. `python setup.py install`

The key is step #3. I've noticed that the changes don't stick if the `build` directory isn't removed first. However, I don't know why this step is necessary and I can't find any references to having to do this and why. This is true for both Windows and Mac OSX. Can somebody please provide a rationale or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`python setup.py install` is implicitly equivalent to [two subcommands](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#splitting-the-job-up):

1. [`build`](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-building-works), which puts the files to install into the `build` directory, and
2. [`install`](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works), which copies files from the `build/lib` directory into the installation directory.

It appears that the first step is only performed when necessary, i.e. when you run `python setup.py install` without first removing the `build` directory, you are installing stale modules from the previous build.

To have changes take effect immediately while developing, you should run `python setup.py develop`, which creates a link in the installation directory back to the source code.